# REMOVE DUPLICATES from lINKED LIST. How come this code works and this one doesn't?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, linked-list

#This work despite not being returned cur but linkedlist in  removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


def removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList(linkedList):
    cur = linkedList
    while cur.next is not None:
        if cur.value == cur.next.value:
            cur.next = cur.next.next
        else:
            cur = cur.next

    return linkedList
```

#This doesn't work

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None


def removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList(linkedList):
    
    while linkedList.next is not None:
        if linkedList.value == linkedList.next.value:
            linkedList.next = linkedList.next.next
        else:
            linkedList = linkedList.next

    return linkedList
```

I would have expected in my code the second one to be able to get a linkedList without duplicates , but above all what amazes me is that in the first one it is not returned cur , and it still works I don't understand therefore where the change occurs

Comment: At the end if the 2nd one `linkedList` is pointing to the last item in the list. Are doing something like: `linkedList = removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList(linkedList)`? This will set the original `linkedList` to the last item.

Comment: In the first one, since you don't modify `linkedList`, at the end it will still point to the first item in the list and `return linkedList` returns that.

Comment: But it all depends on how you call it. Please create a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

If the caller expects to get the linked list **as a return value** from the function, then indeed the second version will not work, as that function will always return a list with just one node in it -- the last node.

Initially, `linkedlist` references the head node of your linked list, and when potentially some duplicate-valued nodes are removed from that list, it should **still** reference the first node of your linked list. So in short, your code should not assign a different reference to `linkedlist` and then return *that*.

It may help to visualise this. Let's take an example list that has 3 nodes and has no duplicates: 1, 2, and 3. Then at the start of the good function, the state is like this:

```
    cur
     ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
     ↑
  linkedList
```

So both `linkedList` and `cur` reference the same node just before the loop starts. As there are no duplicate values, in each iteration we'll execute the `else` part, and so after the first execution of `cur = cur.next` we get:

```
                    cur
                     ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
     ↑
  linkedList
```

The `while` condition is still true, so a next iteration is executed:

```
                                    cur
                                     ↓
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
     ↑
  linkedList
```

At this point the `while` condition is false, and we're ready to return a reference to the linked list. It is clear that if we would return `cur` now, the caller would only have access to that node, and no longer to the first two nodes. It really is necessary to return the reference to the *first* node, i.e. we must `return linkedList`.

Note that it is of little importance whether nodes were deleted in the process or not. Either way, the loop will end when `cur` references the *last* node in the list, and `linkedList` still references the *first* node in the list. The caller is interested in receiving a reference to the *first* node, as otherwise they have no way to have access to all nodes of that list.

In the wrong version of the code, it will be `linkedList` that "walks" to the right -- just like `cur` did in the above process, and then `return linkedList` will not be helpful for the caller for the reasons explained above. In that version the last state is this one:

```
┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ data: 1   │   │ data: 2   │   │ data: 3   │
│ next: ──────► │ next: ──────► │ next: null│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
                                     ↑
                                  linkedList
```

This `linkedList` variable can not be used to reach to the first node in the list. There is no way to get there via `next` references. `linkedList` can only "see" one node, and so it represents a list with just one node.

---

On a final note: if the caller of `removeDuplicatesFromLinkedList` **ignores** the returned reference, and just continues to work with the reference they passed as argument to the function, then the caller will have no problem. Their reference is still to the first node of the list, and they can still iterate it and find that the duplicates have been removed.